# Three.js and collision detection

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

I'm quite new in 3D and Threejs.

I set up a scene with a ground, on the top of the ground lots of cubes.

http://jsfiddle.net/whurp02s/1/

I'm trying to select cubes that cross the yellow rectangle.

So I looked at exemple on internet and found the Raycaster object and it's intersectObject function

```
//**************** colision detection
    var caster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var collisions = [];

    var rays = [
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1),
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, -1),
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1),
      new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, -1),
      new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 1)
    ];

    for ( var i = 0; i < rays.length; i += 1 ) {
        caster.set( squareTL.position, rays[i] );

        for( var boxId in boxGroup ) {
            var boxObj = boxGroup[boxId];

            collisions = caster.intersectObject( boxObj );

            if ( collisions.length ) {
                console.log(collisions);
            } else console.log("no colision");
        }

    }
```

But 0 collision are found.

There is something obvious that I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your jsfiddle code and I've seen a few things that should help:

-Your "boxGroup" array needs to be populated with another array containing the object and not the object itself

-The statement: if ( collisions.length) should be changed to (collisions.length >0) . In case the length is > 1

-Optional actions: Add your collision logic into an animation/run loop

-I would create a new JSfeedle code specific to collition work with less objects. It should be easier for you to debug and understand.

Good luck,
J3zusla